# Check if a range contains text from the another range

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Both the range A1:A3 and B1:B3 contain some text. I would like to have the range B1:B3 have a function that checks if a text in one of its cells can be also found in the range A1:A3. In this case, that specific cell should then have lets say, background-color green. How could I achieve this in Google Sheets? In the example image cell B3 contains the text that can be also found on cell A2, and that's why the background-color is green. That's what I would like to happen, automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting, use as a custom forumula

```
=len($B1)*countif(A:A; "*"&$B1&"*")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet so I can have a closer look?

Comment: @Tane Did you set `Apply to Range` to `B:B` or similar? Also, did you set `Format cells if...` to `Custom formula is`?